# Adding warmup requests to App Engine on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When deploying my app to App Engine Standard's Python 3 runtime, how can I avoid request latency during an update to a new version, or starting new instances? Can I create some type of "warmup request"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to configure custom warmup requests for your app. First, add the `inbound_services` directive and a corresponding handler in your `app.yaml` file:

```
inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: main.py
```

Then, define a warmup route in your `main.py` file:

```
@app.route('/_ah/warmup')
def warmup():
    """Warm up an instance of the app."""
    pass  # For example, initiate a db connection
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests for more details.